# Problems in TableLayout for custom ListView in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

In my `Android` app I'm retrieving data from server using `JSON`. To display that data, I'm using a custom `ListView` that has 3 static images and two `TextViews`. Data is displaying in `ListView` but in different manner.
[image: image1]

**I want output like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3RiL.png) image.**
 But my output list is different in which sometimes those numbers go missing from list.
[image: image2]
Here after 104, numbers 105 and 106 is missing and then 110 is missing. I am not getting any idea why output is like this. Here's my `xml` layout code below:

**XML Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="0,1,2"
    android:shrinkColumns="1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/SrNo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:text="SR NO."
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Expert Name Here."
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/edit"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_view"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/delete"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: i think your first image output are same...check it

Comment: @Mohit no both are different images. I need output like first image in proper manner like no missing numbers.

Comment: Can you show us your adapter code and your json?

Comment: @Boss but the problem is in layout file not in json. I'm getting proper output from server.

Comment: what about your adapter?

Comment: @Boss adapter is also working fine that's why I'm able to display this output.

Comment: have you tried setting weights?

Comment: No..I didn't try weights. @Sangeeta

Comment: then put some weights. some time what happens if a textview takes more space other one hides. try setting weights. it should work i guess.

Comment: @Sangeeta tried..but numbers are still missing.

Comment: numbers you are getting fro json or you manually putting that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91904/discussion-between-user3519241-and-sangeeta).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've almost been there within the discussion with @Sangeeta.

Since [`TableRow`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.html) is inherited from [`LinearLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) the concept of [`weight`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight) is valid for it too, according to which the `layout_width` attribute has to be set to `0dp` in order for a view to be spreaded horizontally.

The following needs to be changed:

1. Remove `android:stretchColumns="0,1,2"`
2. set `android:layout_width="0dp"` wherever `layout_weight` attribute is used.

(Note: I left only relevant attributes for the question)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:shrinkColumns="1">

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/SrNo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.25">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/edit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/delete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```